# Mean of boolean list

Tags: functions

In python I'm used to doing something like `np.mean([True, False, True......])` to compute the fraction of `True` values in a list. Is there some equivalent in mathematica?

Using `Cases` or `Count` seems way too verbose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Boole`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html) to convert truth values to numbers.

```
Mean@Boole@{True, False, True}
(* 2/3 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {True, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, True}
```

Using Mean gives:

```
Mean[list]
Out: 1/10 (3 False + 7 True)
```

Then you can replace False and True with 0 and 1 respectively:

```
Mean[list] /. False -> 0 /. True -> 1
Out: 7/10
```